# WebRTC iOS implementation thread related issue

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, webrtc, videochat

I am working on Audio Video call in my app using WebRTC. I have compiled and added latest WebRTC library in my iOS project. Now I am facing few issues related to threads with WebRTC API's.

Following is the flow of call connection with other user through my own server.

- User initiates call with other user. Here I am allocating all WebRTC related objects, in my case it is voice engine. This is done on background thread using global queue. Initialization of voice engine is initialization of all required classes in voice engine module.
- Call is given to the server for fetching session id for connecting with other user. On success callback, calling `CreateChannel` method of `VoEBase` class. This for creating audio channels. This success block also runs on background thread using global queue.

Now here is problem, after receiving session id when methods for channel creation gets called app is crashing. I have complied library in debug mode to get logs. In logs it is showing following error,

```
# Check failed: thread_checker_.CalledOnValidThread()
```

I have searched on internet for this issue and what I understood is, we should call voice engines methods from same thread. In my case I am calling initialization methods and create methods from background thread using global queue. But global queue has five threads which it uses for performing tasks (I have read this in Apple Docs). So there is no guaranty that these methods will get called on same thread as it is handled by global queue.

I need to resolve this. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Ashish, Did you fixed this?

Comment: @PabloMartinez yes I have fixed this issue.

Comment: May I ask how? Thanks!

Comment: I handled it at Objective-C level. I already handling all WebRTC related functionality in singleton class. As the issue was with thread there was need to call all engine related methods from same thread which was used for creating engine object. So now I am calling all engine methods form my custom separate thread which I am using for all WebRTC related functionality.